# How to learn new spells?

Tags: might-and-magic-x-legacy

One of my party members knows Earth magic and I need the regeneration spell to heal my group.

I assumed that I would get the spell by increasing the charachter's skill to Expert level, but the character still doesn't know it.

How do characters learn new skills? Is there a special trainer for that? The character already visited a trainer who taught the Expert level in Earth magic.

Comment: If it's anything like previous M&M games, you need to find/buy spell books.

Comment: Yeah I played M&M VI but haven't seen anything like scrolls yet... Maybe the trainers are selling them, I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Sorpigal-by-the-Sea, the first town you enter, the spell vendor is right next to the exit from town (to your right if you're facing the exit).  Simply go to his shop and buy them for each character that has the ability to cast them.  Novice spells are around 350 gold per spell per character, and you need to buy it separately for each character.  I haven't been past the second town, so I can't be certain where the next ones are.  But, each time, it's always buying it from someone to learn the spell.